# Flutter project for external testers (iOS via TestFlight & Android via Firebase App Distribution) with Firebase AppCheck in debug mode, how?

Tags: flutter, debugging, token, release

I want to release iOS and Android app for UATs (made with Flutter) with AppCheck active and calling Cloud Functions and Firebase Storage but have no idea how to keep AppCheck in debug mode (with debug tokens if required).
Builds are distributed via TestFlight and Firebase App Distribution respectively, so the default attestation, when apps are distributed outside of the stores, is not possible (at least for Android; no idea what about iOS app via TestFlight).

How to prepare the apps to let them talk to Cloud Functions and Firebase Storage so that they are not rejected by AppCheck?

I've built and installed on Android phone the release apk and it couldn't be accepted by AppCheck - all requests rejected with code 401.